# htaccess rewrite rule for sub domain 301 redirect - WordPress set up

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been looking into this and had a question for a 301 redirect. I am using WordPress and used to have about 5 different sites using subdomains that are now just going to be one site at the root level.

So basically I want sub.yourdomain.com, sub2.yourdomain.com and sub3.yourdomain.com to redirect permanently to yourdomain.com. Wordpress already has a rewrite rule so was not sure if I add my 301's to that or create a new rule.

Here is what I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN SEO Redirects

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.yourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.yourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub3.yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

# END SEO Redirects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this rule before default WP rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub|sub2|sub3)\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```